# why does my jquery dialog box disappears after a few seconds?

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

i have a form with a textarea and a button. if the button is clicked while the textarea is empty, the form will reload and generate an error message. otherwise, the form will redirect to another page. now, i integrated a jquery dialog box. when the button is clicked the dialog box should appear and ask a yes or no question. the problem is when i click the button the dialog box appears but disappears after a few seconds. how can i fix this? i'm using php for the form and jquery for the dialog box.

ps. in php, when you click a button in a form the page will reload right? i think this has something to do with the disappearing of the box because it disappears right before it reloads.

here's my code

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<? echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="myRedirect();">
          <p class="style16">
          <div align="left">

            <p><span class="style5">Rules:</span>
            <?          
            if($_POST['continue']) {
                if($_POST['rules']==null) {
                    echo $_SESSION['nature']."<font color='red' size='3'><b>Please enter the rules.</b></font><br>";
                }
            }
            ?>
              <input type="hidden" name="other_id" value="<? echo $_SESSION['other_id']; ?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden1" value="<? echo $_SESSION['hidden1']; ?>">
            </p>

            <p>
              <textarea name="rules" rows="7" cols="49"></textarea>

              <br />
            </p>
            <div id="dialog" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Is the judge/speaker/facilitator from UST?</p>
</div>
            <p><input type="submit" name="continue" id="continue" value="Continue"/>
            <input type="reset" name="clear" value="Clear"></p>
              <center>


    <!--<input type="submit" name="clear2" id="clear2" value="Clear" onClick="textfield.value="" textfield2.value="" textarea.value="" textarea2.value="" 

    textarea3.value="" textarea4.value="" textarea5.value="" textarea6.value="" file.value="" "/>-->
                  </center>
                </p>
              </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: code plz without that will be hard guess...

Comment: Flavius is correct about having to use return false;  I just want to add something- You said "in php, when you click a button in a form the page will reload right?"  PHP is ONLY server side.  There is no such thing as a PHP form or a PHP button.  They are HTML elements.  It is only because you have the action as $PHP_SELF that it directs to the same page (Just look at the html source in the browser to verify this)

Comment: i placed onclick="myRedirect();" in my submit button and onsubmit="what();" in my form but the dialog box still disappears. how can i make a page redirect to a certain page after clicking a button in the dialog box?

Comment: Are you spamming or what? This is the 3rd question you've asked without ever responding to any answers. And this question is identical to another you asked las night...

Answer (score 0):

To keep the form from submitting, you need a "return false" in its onsubmit event.